# SwiftUI DatePicker: Is there a way to make it so they can't use the keyboard to edit the fields?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, datepicker

I have an app that I am working on with multiple datepickers being used on the screen at any one time. I have the pickers themselves working, but I don't want the keyboard to show for editing.

I prefer to have the user change the time by using the scroll wheels, rather than the keyboard. I have been searching for a way to stop the keyboard from appearing, but I haven't had any luck finding a solution.

I would basically want a smaller version of the old graphical picker wheels.

Here is the code for my picker:

```
struct TimePicker: View {
    @Binding var time: Date
    
    var body: some View {
        
        DatePicker("", selection: $time, displayedComponents: .hourAndMinute)
            .datePickerStyle(GraphicalDatePickerStyle())  
    }
}
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why?  That's a terrible user experience.  I far prefer to tab between fields and type the digits.

Comment: It is the pop up keyboard on iOS devices that I would like to remove. I agree that it is easier to tab between fields, but that isn’t an option on iOS devices.

Comment: OK, but shouldn't that be a user choice?  There's a button to drop the keyboard if it's in the way.

Comment: I would normally agree, but the keyboard has some strange inconsistent behavior in SwiftUI. Some things work fine with it in the simulator, but don't work on my iPad. The same things work fine ok on an iPhone, but block the part you are editing. I am sure that I can work out ways to fix all of the issues that are happening, but it would be much easier if the keyboard just didn't pop up on the iOS devices.

Answer (score -1):

The answer isn't obvious from the documentation, but it's actually quite straightforward.

Just replace `.datePickerStyle(GraphicalDatePickerStyle())`

with: `.datePickerStyle(WheelDatePickerStyle())`

as so:

```
struct TimePicker: View {
@Binding var time: Date

var body: some View {
    
    DatePicker("", selection: $time, displayedComponents: .hourAndMinute)
        .datePickerStyle(WheelDatePickerStyle())  
}
```

}